# react-dev-tools Copy to Clipboard does not work

Tags: reactjs

I am using [react-dev-tools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html) browser extension for Firefox. Version 4.27.0 of the extension, version 107 of Firefox.

When using the dev tools, you can view the state of each component. Right clicking on one of these entries gives the option to "Copy Value to Clipboard". Only problem is, nothing is ever actually copied to my clipboard. What am I doing wrong? Or is this feature just broken? OS is Windows 11, clipboard works fine otherwise.